# Libgdx freetypefont not displaying right border color

Tags: libgdx

If i set a brown border color for my font it doesn't display the proper color

this is my code:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new 
FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.TTF"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 40;
parameter.borderWidth = 3f;
parameter.borderColor = Color.YELLOW; <--- COLOR

BitmapFont bitmapFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);

label = new Label("text", new Label.LabelStyle(bitmapFont, Color.BLACK));
label.setPosition(1000/2, 600/2);
```

for example `parameter.borderColor = Color.YELLOW` displays a black color and not a yellow one. Any answers appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way :

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.TTF"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 40;
parameter.borderWidth = 3f;
parameter.color=Color.BLACK;           //<-- set Foreground (required for non-black borders) color
parameter.borderColor = Color.YELLOW;

BitmapFont bitmapFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);

label = new Label("text", new Label.LabelStyle(bitmapFont, Color.WHITE)); //<- change Color.BLACK to Color.WHITE 
label.setPosition(1000/2, 600/2);
```

I've assigned `Color.BLACK` color to `FreeTypeFontParameter` and changed `LabelStyle` color to `Color.WHITE`

Comment: For more flexible fonts check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxPf1M7YORU